# Get Selected Time from TimePicker in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, timepicker

Since they said anything that Java can do, C# can do better ...Decided to engineer an alarm app in Xamarin Android and i cant seem to get the value of the selected time in C#...A variable known as triggerTime which should play some music or show an alert dialog when the alarm time matures needs that value...
Here is xml for the TimePicker...

```
 <TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Here is the C# code that has the timepicker defined in the AlarmActivity.cs

```
 base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Alarm);
     TimePicker timePicker2 = this.FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.timePicker1);
//Code to getTime that user selects
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `TimeChanged` event to get the time when the timepicker changed.

**xml：**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/timePicker1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code behind:**

```
  TextView textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);
        TimePicker timePicker1 = FindViewById<TimePicker>(Resource.Id.timePicker1);
        timePicker1.TimeChanged += delegate
        {
            var h = timePicker1.CurrentHour;
            var m = timePicker1.CurrentMinute;
            textView.Text = h + ":" + m;

        };
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin provides a complete example of using [TimePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/controls/pickers/time-picker)

basically, you need to implement `IOnTimeSetListener` which has a `OnTimeSet` method

```
public void OnTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
{
    // hourOfDate and minute are the user's selected values
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason lemme try it, Thanks for the link also and could you please add code i can use to get the hour and minute selected in that section that you've commented

Comment: the Picker will call `OnTimeSet` and pass in the selected values as the arguments as noted